# Docusign Salesforce Button not utilizing docusign template merge fields

Tags: templates, button, merge, salesforce, docusignapi

I'm utilizing Doscusign for salesforce and have made a custom button. The process works fine but I'm having trouble getting some of the template merge fields to auto-populate with information relating to the signer.

I've tried a custom merge field in docusign admin but that didn't have any luck either.

Any help would be appreciated! My code for the button is below:

````
[
"SourceID"=Opportunity.Id,
"DSEID"=0,
"DST"=if(OR(Account.PersonMailingState = "California",Account.PersonMailingState = "CA"),"05b0bc86-6980-48d5-b415-9046d539bd3f, 6d9413a9-d702-416b-a1c6-fda9b402d0ad", "05b0bc86-6980-48d5-b415-9046d539bd3f"),
"OCO"="Send",
"CES"='MIB and Authorization',
"CEM"='Hello Account.FirstName,\\n\\n Please sign the following document.\\n\\nThank you_COMMA_\\nNavy Mutual',
"CRL"="Email~"+Account.PersonEmail+";Role~Applicant"+";FirstName~"+LEFT(Opportunity.Name,FIND(" ",Opportunity.Name)-1) +";LastName~"+MID(LEFT(Opportunity.Name,FIND("-",Opportunity.Name)-1),FIND(" ",Opportunity.Name)+1,LEN(Opportunity.Name))+";SignNow~1",
"CCRM"='Applicant~Signer 1'
])}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Merge fields would be created either on the DocuSign account or in Custom Tags in the DocuSign Admin object in Salesforce, they would act separately to what you define in the custom button code.

Here's a bit of an older [guide](https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-user-guide-create-merge-fields-user) that outlines how you can create Merge Fields, but I would advise reaching out to support for a bit more information. https://support.docusign.com/